# Error forwarding the request Read timed out [chrome #11-12] at WebDriverError ONLY on the last browser instance on selenium grid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, docker-compose, selenium-grid, e2e-testing

I keep on running into this issue whenever the last test is being run.
We run our protractor tests on a Selenium grid that is fired up via Docker and kicked off whenever a commit is made.

But this is the super weird thing:
Sometimes all the tests pass flawlessly and sometimes any test that is being run on the last firefox or chrome instance just hangs and sits there and eventually throws the following error:

> WebDriverError: Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request Read timed out [chrome #11-12]     at WebDriverError

The test is random because we have `shardTestFiles: true,` and we have `max instances` set to `10`

Also due the fact that this is being run on the grid it is impossible to figure out whether there is something wrong with the test or not, because the same test would pass if it is not the one randomly picked to run on the last browser instance.

I am also not too sure if this is a protractor issue or a docker-selenium issue.

Is anyone else experiencing the same issue?

Comment: Do you run your tests on IE also on GRID?.. Can you once run the tests only on chrome and firefox to see if you are still seeing the issue?

Comment: @AdityaReddy: We run them only on ff and chrome, i did try running them only on each of the browsers and i still see the same thing, only difference being that this time it gives the timeout error on random tests and not on the last test on the last browser instance.